# Pagination in TypeORM, NestJS

Tags: node.js, database, nestjs, backend, typeorm

I have `multiple search condition` in my `form`. if user does not enter anything then all the `data` should be return. if he gives `some search input` then only those `matching` record should be return.

Below code is working fine. the only thing is ,sometimes record are coming around 30-40 with filter condition as well so I have been given requirement to introduce `pagination`. we have to show 10 record at a time in page with or without filter condition.

Could you please guide me how can I introduce `pagination` in below code.

```
async findAll(queryCertificateDto: QueryCertificateDto): Promise<Certificate[]> {

    const { certificateNo, requestStatus, protoColNo, noOfSubjects} =queryCertificateDto

    const query = this.certificateRepository.createQueryBuilder('certificate');

    if (certificateNo) {
        query.andWhere('certificate.certificateNo=:certificateNo', { certificateNo });
    }

    if (requestStatus) {
        query.andWhere('certificate.requestStatus=:requestStatus', {
            requestStatus,
        });
    }

    if (protoColNo) {
        query.andWhere('certificate.protoColNo=:protoColNo', { protoColNo });
    }

    if (noOfSubjects) {
        query.andWhere('certificate.noOfSubjects=:noOfSubjects', { noOfSubjects });
    }
    const certificates = await query.getMany();
    return certificates;
}
```

Comment: with `query.take(10).skip(x)`?

Comment: thank you, then how to take next 10? could you please suggestion modification in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export const getAllFaqs = () => async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
  const {
    query: { userType ,page ,perPage},
  } = req;
  const faqsPagesRepository = getCustomRepository(FaqsPageRepository);

  let where: FindConditions<Faqs> = {};

  if (userType) {
    where = { ...where, userType };
  }
  const limit =Number(perPage);
  const offset=(Number(page)-1)*limit;
  const result = await faqsPagesRepository.findAndCount({
    where,
    take:limit,
    skip:offset,
  });

  res.status(200).json({ result });
};
```